# Add custom link fields in header tab in magento 2

Tags: magento2, header

I need to add new custom link fields(chat) in header tab.

For example luma page has these link fields in header page (create account, signup), same header place i want to add chat link in header top, suggest me how to do this.

Comment: Hey Rajkumar did this work for you? If so please accept it as correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, go to your custom theme `app/desing/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` file.

There you will find the below with the links you mentioned, just add the part below for your chat

```
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
....

                 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="my-link1">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Chat</argument>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">Your_Link_To_The_Chat</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>                   
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```